# Oracle is not starting, giving not logged on error [Centos]

Tags: unix, oracle11g, virtualbox, database-administration

I have a centos box (.vdi) and have installed oracle in it. oracle is running fine on my system but once i moved this vdi file to another system and tried to start oracle through STARTUP command its giving me error not logged on. Any pointer will be helpful.

Comment: Please ORA-XXXX error in the studio...

Answer (score 0):

Check IP address of the CENT OS machine. The present IP address should be same as when you are installing oracle database. Check Listener.ora and tnsnames.ora files have correct entries